# He may/might/could practice playing the guitar regularly from now on. - Does it express uncertainty?

Tags: modal-verbs

I think someone will do something, but I am not sure. Can I use may/might/could to express the uncertainty?

**Example 1.**

> He wants to learn how to play the guitar. He may/might/could practice playing the guitar regularly from now on.

Comment: This is rather an odd choice of example, because if someone wants to learn an instrument they _need to/ought to_ practise regularly! But, yes, you can use _may, might_ or _could_ to speculate about someone's future actions.

Answer (score 2):

Both "may" and "might" are good options:

> He may practice regularly from now on.

> He might practice regularly from now on.

"Could" is also possible but doesn't work quite as well, because that seems to imply something about his ability to practice.